# sqlzoo "More Join" #15

Tags: sql, database

Can someone show me why my solution doesn't work for this challenge?

http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/More_JOIN_operations

**15. List the films released in the year 1978 ordered by the number of actors in the cast, then by title.**

```
SELECT title, COUNT(actorid) AS actors FROM movie
JOIN casting ON id = movieid
WHERE yr = 1978
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY actors DESC
```

Comment: You aren't ordering by the title.  You're only ordering by the actors (and you're ordering that `DESC` which the question doesn't ask for).

Answer (score 3):

Because you're missing the second-level `ORDER BY` term.  It should be:

```
ORDER BY actors DESC, title
```

(The question doesn't explicitly ask for descending order, but their official “correct answer” is ordered that way.)

Comment: I tried this but got an error message: Error:
Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause

Comment: @veron: I didn't get that error.  Do you still have the `GROUP BY title` clause?

Comment: That's right. The GROUP BY clause is supposed to go before ORDER BY actors DESC, title. It works now.

Answer (score 2):

Since the requirements ask you to order by the number of actors and then title. Therefore, you have to add `title` in `Order by` clause:

```
SELECT title, COUNT(actorid) AS actors FROM movie
 JOIN casting ON id = movieid
 WHERE yr = 1978
 GROUP BY title
 ORDER BY actors DESC, title
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct a1.name from actor a1
join casting c1 on c1.actorid = a1.id
join movie m1 on c1.movieid = m1.id
where m1.id in (
select distinct m.id from movie m
join casting c on c.movieid = m.id
join actor a  on c.actorid = a.id
where a.name = 'Art Garfunkel')
and a1.name <> 'Art Garfunkel'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It's good you're showing initiative by answering to this post. It's recommended that you explain your answer rather than just posting code.